# Subset sequence data in fasta file based on IDs stored in listed data frames

Tags: r, subset, fasta, seq

I am trying to subset one FASTA file (containing multiple sequences) into several smaller ones based on IDs I stored in a list of data frames (and

I have a FASTA called fastafile like this:

```
 fastafile <- dput(fastafile)
structure(list(r1 = "acatattggaggccgaaacaatgaggcgtgatcaactcagtatatcac", 
    r2 = "ctaacctctcccagtgtggaacctctatctcatgagaaagctgggatgag", 
    r3 = "atttcctcctgctgcccgggaggtaacaccctggacccctggagtctgca", 
    r4 = "acatattggaggccgaaacaatgaggcgtgatcaactcagtatatcgg", 
    r5 = "ctaacctctcccagtgtggaacctctatctcatgagaaagctgggatgg", 
    r6 = "atttcctcctgctgcccgggaggtaacaccctggacccctggagtctgg"), .Names = c("r1", 
"r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6"))
```

that I loaded using seqinr package like that:

```
fastafile <- read.fasta(file = "fastafile.fasta", 
                       seqtype = c("DNA","AA"),
                       as.string = TRUE, set.attributes = FALSE)
```

I load a table with my IDs and some expression values

```
GOI <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "ID        T1        T2
1 r1 1.1 2.1
2 r2 1.2 2.2
3 r3 1.1 2.2
4 r4 1.2 2.1
5 r5 1.1 2.1
6 r6 1.2 2.2")
```

and split them into manageable subsets

```
GOI.split <- split(GOI,rep(1:3,each=2))
```

giving me

```
> GOI.split
$`1`
  ID  T1  T2
1 r1 1.1 2.1
2 r2 1.2 2.2

$`2`
  ID  T1  T2
3 r3 1.1 2.2
4 r4 1.2 2.1

$`3`
  ID  T1  T2
5 r5 1.1 2.1
6 r6 1.2 2.2
```

Now I would like to subset my sequences based on the IDs in the `GOI.split` data frames. In this mock example it should be two sequences per list item. To get the subset for the first one of the listed data frames I can say:

```
FASTA.1 <- fastafile[c(which(names(fastafile) %in% GOI.split[[1]][,1]))]
# $r1
# [1] "acatattggaggccgaaacaatgaggcgtgatcaactcagtatatcac"
# 
# $r2
# [1] "ctaacctctcccagtgtggaacctctatctcatgagaaagctgggatgag"
```

(and so on) however I would like to subset for all data frames in one swift move to have a list with my desired fastas (3 list items containing, in this case, 2 sequences each). I tried:

```
FASTAs <- lapply(fastafile, function(i)
{fastafile[c(which(names(fastafile) %in% GOI.split[[i]][ ,1]))]})
```

Could somebody please tell me why this is not working and what I have to do instead.

Thanks

Comment: A reproducible excerpt of fastafile may be needed. To me, it looks like you are selecting columns with names like `1.1` and `1.2`, which is strange in vanilla R, but maybe normal in seqinr.

Comment: @Frank thanks, I'd like to add a reproducible excerpt, but I do not know how. Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: @Frank & thanks for making me aware that I'm not succeeding in making myself clear. What I want R to do is: 1. Select the ID column of my `GOI.split` items, 2. match these IDs to the sequence names and 3. split the original fasta the same way `GOI.split` is divided (and preferentially return it as a list).

Comment: One way to provide fastafile would be to call `dput(fastafile)`, then copy and paste the result of that here.  That will allow others to copy and paste the data into R.  Take a look at [how to ask a reproducible R question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more pointers.

Comment: Thanks, other @Frank , for posting that . Good reference there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the following code:

```
split(fastafile[GOI$ID], rep(1:3,each=2))


$`1`
$`1`$r1
[1] "acatattggaggccgaaacaatgaggcgtgatcaactcagtatatcac"

$`1`$r2
[1] "ctaacctctcccagtgtggaacctctatctcatgagaaagctgggatgag"


$`2`
$`2`$r3
[1] "atttcctcctgctgcccgggaggtaacaccctggacccctggagtctgca"

$`2`$r4
[1] "acatattggaggccgaaacaatgaggcgtgatcaactcagtatatcgg"


$`3`
$`3`$r5
[1] "ctaacctctcccagtgtggaacctctatctcatgagaaagctgggatgg"

$`3`$r6
[1] "atttcctcctgctgcccgggaggtaacaccctggacccctggagtctgg"
```

As to why your `lapply` code is not working.  One reason is that you are passing in `fastafile`, and you should be passing in indices.

So you are trying this:

```
fastafile[c(which(names(fastafile) %in% GOI.split[[fastafile[[1]]]][ ,1]))]
#named list()
```

When you should do this:

```
fastafile[c(which(names(fastafile) %in% GOI.split[[1]][ ,1]))]
#$r1
#[1] "acatattggaggccgaaacaatgaggcgtgatcaactcagtatatcac"
#
#$r2
#[1] "ctaacctctcccagtgtggaacctctatctcatgagaaagctgggatgag"
```

So, to fix it, pass in `1:length(GOI.split)` instead of `fastafile`:

```
lapply(1:length(GOI.split), function(i)
 {fastafile[c(which(names(fastafile) %in% GOI.split[[i]][ ,1]))]})

[[1]]
[[1]]$r1
[1] "acatattggaggccgaaacaatgaggcgtgatcaactcagtatatcac"

[[1]]$r2
[1] "ctaacctctcccagtgtggaacctctatctcatgagaaagctgggatgag"


[[2]]
[[2]]$r3
[1] "atttcctcctgctgcccgggaggtaacaccctggacccctggagtctgca"

[[2]]$r4
[1] "acatattggaggccgaaacaatgaggcgtgatcaactcagtatatcgg"


[[3]]
[[3]]$r5
[1] "ctaacctctcccagtgtggaacctctatctcatgagaaagctgggatgg"

[[3]]$r6
[1] "atttcctcctgctgcccgggaggtaacaccctggacccctggagtctgg"
```